# Adobe Acrobat 2022 : Only the first page is printed from a pdf document

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-acrobat

I have Windows 11 22H2 , and Adobe Acrobat Pro 2022.

I have a strange problem. I open a pdf document with several pages and try to print from acrobat.
Only the first page is printed . But it seems that the document is sent to printer because nothing remain on queue. But after the first page is printed , the printer stop without any error and does not print other pages. I've tried with several pdf documents , and it's the same situation.
But if i open the same pdf document with Microsoft Edge and try to print, everything is ok , all the pages are printed correctly.

What can I do?

Comment: Acrobat Pro 2022 (Subscription) is working and printing fine here.  Uninstall Acrobat, restart, install it and test.

Comment: @John I did a clean installation of windows , i\ve installed Acrobat 2022 and printer. The problem is the same. I did this in 2 different computers that are connected to the same printer via network. The problem is the same in both computers.

Comment: I am not sure. I am using a local network printer, and all is well.  Perhaps try a different printer or reinstall the printer driver.